# Design issue: bounty awards are crazy hard to read

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

See the +100 in this screencap? (From https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/16236/60) If you're like me you had to spend at least 15 seconds staring wondering why there's a blue box below the vote button before realizing it was a bounty award!

[image: Crazy hard to read numbers]

Is there any way we can make the font stand out more against the background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the fix will be on live after the next production build.